# Why is my UITextField being cut off at the trailing edge?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, autolayout, uitextfield

I'm trying to learn Auto Layout and playing around with various view combinations. I have various views containing other views, but the one I'm having trouble with is one that contains a label and a text field. They are set up like this:

[image]

There are several constraints set up on these, such as center Y alignment between the label, text field, and parent view, 0 leading edge for the label, and a hard coded value (12, but irrelevant) for the trailing edge of the text field. I had initially had it as a 0 trailing edge, aligning it with the parent container. However, the right edge of the text field seems to be cutting off and I have no idea why... I Started increasing the distance, thinking that may be there's a margin issue, but nothing seems to help!
Would love any input.

Comment: May have to decrease the trailing space after `points` and decrease the width of your `UITextField` such that it fits within the bounds of your cell (or view).

Comment: I hope there may be constraints problem for the right side. Apart from textfield what you have on right side? It will be great if you send the demo project of it.

Comment: @Sohil - you are right, it was an issue with the neighboring view. I set all the veiws to be different colors to see the outlines better and it came jumping out at me. Thank you!